# Excel Macro to insert column and lookup text and splitt with header

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet which contains following content:

I have worked on a macro which does following:-

1. Find the column having Header ABC  **{DONE}**

**If statement** to check if the column heading AB already exists before the split happens. **{PENDING}**

2. Insert ten new columns adjacent to ABC with name of AB and CD ... etc **{DONE}**
3. Then split the ABC cell content into respective cells of AB and CD; by matching the first two characters with respective column headers note (ABC column may have one many content having similar first two characters ) **{PENDING}**
4. Follow step (3) till end of column ABC content. **{DONE}**

I have written following code :-

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub NumFormat()

       Dim colNum As Integer
    colNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="ABC", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

        'insert two columns
        ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
        ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ' New col headings
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 1).Value = "AB"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 2).Value = "CD"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 3).Value = "EF"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 4).Value = "GH"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 5).Value = "IJ"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 6).Value = "KL"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 7).Value = "MN"
        Dim colRange As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set colRange = .Range(.Cells(2, colNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, colNum))
    End With

    Dim splitStr() As String

Dim vcell As Range
For Each vcell In colRange
    splitStr = Split(vcell.Value, vbLf)
    For Each s In splitStr
        Set cel = ActiveSheet.Cells(vcell.Row, WorksheetFunction.Match(Left(s, 2), ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H1"), 0))
        If cel.Value <> "" Then cel.Value = cel.Value + vbLf
        cel.Value = cel.Value + s
    Next s
Next vcell
    End Sub
```

can anyone help me with this

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I am unable to splitt ABC column cell content in respective inserted column via code

Comment: if the inserted column header is AB then it should search ABC respective cell and copy the line which is starting with character i.e. AB

Comment: I really don't understand the question here. I tried your code and got the desired output. You already getting your desired output.

Comment: my code says 's' variable is undefined

Comment: That's because you never declare `s`. `Option Explicit`, which you have at the very top, means that *every* variable you use must first be declared.  Add `Dim s` to your sub. (I think you'll want `Dim s As String`, but am not positive if you want each part of a split string off the top of my head).

Comment: I am not able to get workable code could you please debug and help me with answer? I took it as variant and then got struck with 'cel' not defined?? desperate need of help

Comment: @monikasingh why don't you say your problem at the first place. Just delete option explicit or define s as string.

Comment: thanks for tip @alisrn but now getting OBJECT error on vcel.Value = cel.Value + vbLf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is worked for me. On Error Resume Next is what you needed.

```
Sub NumFormat()

   Dim colNum As Integer
colNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="ABC", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
Dim s As Variant
Dim cel As Range
    'insert two columns
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
' New col headings
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 1).Value = "AB"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 2).Value = "CD"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 3).Value = "EF"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 4).Value = "GH"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 5).Value = "IJ"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 6).Value = "KL"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 7).Value = "MN"
    Dim colRange As Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set colRange = .Range(.Cells(2, colNum), .Cells(.Cells(5000, colNum).End(3).Row, colNum))
End With

Dim splitStr() As String

Dim vcell As Range
For Each vcell In colRange
splitStr = Split(vcell.Value, vbLf)

For Each s In splitStr
On Error GoTo endy
    Set cel = Cells(vcell.Row, WorksheetFunction.Match(Left(s, 2), ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H1"), 0))
    If cel.Value <> "" Then cel.Value = cel.Value + vbLf
    cel.Value = cel.Value + s
endy:
    Next s
Next vcell
    End Sub
```

Comment: You were also using that function, why didn't it give that error to you at the first place? + I didn't get any error.

Comment: I get it now, There is word with start 2 letters and there is not a match in the column names. Is that the case, can you check? When I corrected it in my worksheet, it worked.

Comment: my problem is ABC column in one cell have multiple line numbers always having XX12345678 wherein based on first two character need to be seprated in adjacent column having same character header. if you see above picture it will be clear.

Comment: I know. You have column up to MN but maybe there is OP12345678 and that causes the problem because match function cant find the OP column and returns an error.

Comment: there is chance but can we skip that kind of number?

Comment: can you post full working code as answer will run same

Comment: HI @alisrn i noticed another bug header is matched but values are posted in pervious cell e.g. CD values are pasted in AB cell -- can you comment??

Comment: Updated. @monikasingh

Comment: please download file:- https goo(dot)gl/MjlkSw

Comment: @monikasingh I cant download, I am at work. Can you check the latest code?

Comment: yes working perfectly can you help me with line wherein if Column range A1 : H1 any column is completely empty we can delete it?

Comment: This is another question. Please ask it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You are using option explicit.

When we use option explicit in our code, we must declare variable before use.
Please declare the variable s and try to run.

Please try to run below code , its working fine on my system.
Let me know the result.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub NumFormat()

       Dim colNum As Integer
    Dim s As Variant
    Dim cel As Variant

    colNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="ABC", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

        'insert two columns
        ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
        ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert
    ' New col headings
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 1).Value = "AB"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 2).Value = "CD"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 3).Value = "EF"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 4).Value = "GH"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 5).Value = "IJ"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 6).Value = "KL"
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 7).Value = "MN"
        Dim colRange As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set colRange = .Range(.Cells(2, colNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, colNum))
    End With

    Dim splitStr() As String

Dim vcell As Range
For Each vcell In colRange
    splitStr = Split(vcell.Value, vbLf)
    For Each s In splitStr
        Set cel = ActiveSheet.Cells(vcell.Row, WorksheetFunction.Match(Left(s, 2), ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H1"), 0))
        If cel.Value <> "" Then cel.Value = cel.Value + vbLf
        cel.Value = cel.Value + s
    Next s
Next vcell
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks but i am getting error of OBJECT on code -- vcel.Value = cel.Value + vbLf